# React useState() hook does not update state when child.shouldComponentUpdate() returns false

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've started reading about React Hooks and tried to rewrite some small components to use them, but I've got a problem with setting state. Basically, when the child component `<Content/>` always returns `false` in `shouldComponentUpdate`, then parent's (`<App/>.setShow`) is called, but it does not update the state and `<Content/>` isn't rendered.

I've prepared a minimal working example below, where `<App/>` is a component based on React Hoos, and `<App2/>` is an equivalent class based Component. The latter one works, so apparently there is some nuance there I don't get.

```js
const {useState} = React;

class Panel extends React.Component {
   shouldComponentUpdate() { return false; } 
   render() { return (<button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Toggle</button>) }
}

class Content extends React.Component {
  render() { return <div>Content</div> }
}

const App = (props) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

  const toggle = () => {
    console.log("Toggling visibility!", show);
    setShow(!show);
  }

  console.log("[App] render()");
  return (<div >
    <h1>Hi at {Date.now()}</h1>
    <Panel onClick={toggle} />
    {show && <Content /> }
  </div>)
}

class App2 extends React.Component {
  state = { show: true }

  render() {
    const toggle = () => {
      console.log("[App] toggle", this.state.show)
      this.setState({ show: !this.state.show })
    }

    console.log("[App] render()");
    return (<div >
      <h1>Hi at {Date.now()}</h1>
      <Panel onClick={toggle} />
      {this.state.show && <Content />}
    </div>)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<div> <App/> <App2/> </div>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
</app>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) because you have [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#:%7E:text=A%20closure%20is%20the%20combination,scope%20from%20an%20inner%20function.) on value of `show` inside `toggle` function.

The closure happens because `shouldComponentUpdate` always returns `false`, so on first render the value of `this.props.onClick` will have stale state of `show === true`, which won't change on subsequential renders.

```
const App = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

  // Closure on value of show
  // const toggle = () => {
  //   console.log("Toggling visibility!", show);
  //   setShow(!show);
  // }

  const toggle = () => {
    setShow(prevState => {
      console.log("Toggling visibility!", prevState);
      return !prevState;
    });
  };

  console.log("[App] render()");
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hi at {Date.now()}</h1>
      <Panel onClick={toggle} />
      {show && <Content />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit gallant-saha-9z8eu]

Comment: Stale closure happens because functional app passes toggle with show in closure as `true`, when toggle is called the app component will re render but Panel will not and still has a toggle function with show as true. Clicking the button again will cause the state to be set to `!true` but since state was already false the functional app won't re render. Class App works because toggle doesn't use closure, it gets the state through `this.state`.